# How to add link to sent email message in Gmail Add-On notification

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

My Gmail Add-On sends out an email and then shows a notification using the API `ActionResponseBuilder.setNotification` with info message "*Invite email sent.*". That all works great.

My question is how to add a link in the notification to the new email message. I assume this is possible since the native Gmail notification does that when sending an email. It shows "*Your message has been sent. View message*", where "View message" is a link.

```
GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(e.messageMetadata.accessToken);
var mail = GmailApp.getMessageById(e.messageMetadata.messageId);
mail.replyAll("Test email");

return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
  .setNotification(
    CardService.newNotification()
      .setText('Invite email sent.')  // how to add a link to new email
      .setType(CardService.NotificationType.INFO)
  )
  .build();
```

As reference the notification of a manually sent email that contains the link.
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for [Gmail Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push)?

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 I don't see how Gmail Push Notifications could be used in a Gmail Add-On. As described on the Push Notifications page, they are to notify a backend server application, either via webhooks or polling.